# Different definitions of quotient maps for uniform spaces 2

Tags: general-topology, uniform-continuity, uniform-spaces

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202634/different-definitions-of-quotient-maps-for-uniform-spaces) I asked a question about $3$ definitions of quotients for uniform spaces being equivalent (uniform space here, is a Hausdorff space together with uniform covers - those can be found on wikipedia).

However, I'm stuck at the proof of point $7$ from Isbell's book "Uniform Spaces".

[image]

I don't understand the first part of this proof. That is, why is $f_0$ uniformly continuous.

If anyone could explain me it I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of $f_0$ as a function is clear from the condition that $f$ and $q$ satisfy together (any $z \in Q$ is of the form $z=q(x)$ for some $x \in X$ and we then define $f_0(z) = f(x)$ for that $x$, which does not really depend on the $x$ we pick by the aforementioned condition, $f_0 \circ q=f$ by construction).

If $Q$ gets the weak preuniformity $\mu_{f_0}$ induced by $f_0$, this means that for any uniform cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $Y$, $f_0^{-1}[\mathcal{U}]$ is in $\mu_{f_0}$, (and these form a generating set) so trivially $f_0$ is uniformly continuous. And their inverse images under $q$ are just $f^{-1}[\mathcal{U}]$ by the commutative property, so uniform in $X$.

Comment: Yes. It wasn't clear to me that $Q$ gets the finest uniformity such that $q:X\to Q$ is uniformly continuous. But now, from proof of point $5$, I see that it can be written $q =pq'$ where $q':X\to Q'$, $p:Q'\to Q$ are uniformly continuous, $p$ is the identity function and $Q'$ has finest uniformity making $q':X\to Q'$ continuous. Since $q$ is a quotient, $p$ is an isomorphism so $Q$ has finest uniformity making $q:X\to Q$ continuous. I didn't realize that. Now that it's finest and what you wrote imply that $f_0$ is uniformly continuous. It all makes sense now, thanks!